# How to read hdf5 files with Python h5py package?

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I'm new to coding and I want to know how to read a hdf5 file using Python. More specifically, I wish to access columns (by name) to extract information.

I can read a h5 file using Pandas like this:

```
pd.read_hdf('file_path.h5')
```

The above doesn't work with my hdf5 file. Now, I'm using the h5py package to read it like this:

```
import h5py
df = h5py.File('filename.hdf5', "r")
```

Now I'm not too sure how to read a particular column. Each column in the dataset has a name like: age, distance (etc...)

This is my 1st question, so I'm happy to give out more info on my problem. :)

Comment: HDF5 isn't organized in columns. I consists of groups and datasets. You need to know the structure in order to read it. If you have the HDF5 commandline tools available, show us the output of `h5ls -r filename.hdf5` which shows the structure

Comment: Your subject line is misleading, since you have found 2 ways of reading such a file, the pandas and `h5py`.  Both work, but on different files.  `h5py` is a numpy interface, close to the 'raw' structure with groups and 'datasets'.  The pandas uses a 'tables' organization. so can't just any HDF5 file.  But it's hard to help without knowning much about how your file is organized.

Comment: Your talk about columns by name and datasets suggests pandas like data.  But withoout knowing the source, and the file organization, we can't say whether the pandas reader should work or not.  And you don't tell us anything about what didn't work.  The `numpy` oriented `h5py` reader isn't organized by 'named columns' - unless the array is a `structured one`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [h5py documentation](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/)? It is very helpful. There are also several good answers in Stack Overflow. Reading a HDF5 file is pretty straightforward (especially if you are familiar with NumPy arrays).

The dtype of the array matches the dataset. If the dataset is homogeneous, it behaves like an ndarray.

Based on your reference to "column" names, it sounds like you have heterogeneous datasets. They are handled like NumPy structured arrays, where the dtype is defined by a list of tuples like this `('field name', dtype)`; one for each field/column.

I extended your example to get you started. (Note: `df` in your code is a h5py file object -- it NOT a dataset!)

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('filename.hdf5', "r") as h5f:
     # this creates a dataset object:
     dataset = h5f[dataset name here]
     # to get the dtype and shape
     print(dataset.dtype, dataset.shape) 
     # adding [()] reads the entire dataset into an array:
     dataset_as_array =  h5f[dataset name here][()] 
     # this extracts a field/column of data from that dataset
     col_array = h5f[dataset name here][column name here] # uses the h5py file object
     # OR
     col_array = dataset[column name here] # uses the dataset object
```

In code above, `dataset` and `h5f[dataset name here]` both reference the dataset and are interchangeable.